# Reporting in MVC4 WebAPI With AngularJS

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, reporting

I have been creating a web application with `MVC4 webAPI` as backend and `AngularJS` for frontend. Now I have been in situation where I have to present `reports`, `invoices` and other such documents from the application. But I don't have any proper tool that could help me to print and download as PDF at the same time.

I had reviewed several products to make that working but haven't got any tool that would fit my purpose to print and PDF conversion to get downloaded.

- **`SSRS Report :`** I did checked the SSRS report with report viewer but as this is a web application, my hosting provider does not provide support for the reportviewer library installed or SSRS controls on the server.
- **`JSPDF:`** I did tried `JSPDF` to print and convert the reports to PDF but the alignment for the tables, colspans and other stuff becomes very messy and complex to work with `JSPDF`.

Can anyone suggest me which would be the best way to create reports which could get download and print with easy setup.

Comment: Do you want to show the pdfs in your app and then be able to print them and download them?

Comment: yes something like that. But if I don't have the view functionality then it is fine. if I just have generate functionality then it would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You can check [jsreport](http://jsreport.net). It is designed for creating static documents like Pdf reports using javascript templating engines on the server. It's free and open sourced on github.

You can run it along .net process using [jsreport.Embedded](http://jsreport.net/learn/net-embedded) nuget package, benefit from [visual studio extension](http://jsreport.net/learn/visual-studio-extension) or even create pdf files directly from your asp.net mvc views using [jsreport.MVC](http://jsreport.net/learn/asp-net-mvc) nuget package.

If your shared hosting provider will block [jsreport.Embedded](http://jsreport.net/learn/net-embedded), you can still connect [jsreport online service](http://jsreport.net/online) which will handle report rendering for you.

P.S.: I'm jsreport author.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't already, i think you should try [DBxtra](http://dbxtra.com), you can upload the Report Web Service component (the web component) to your server without installing anything there, then connect to it from your own computer and design reports from there; it will let you design, print and export to PDF (and other formats) pixel perfect reports just as you wish and you can embed the reports into your own application using [Web Report Widgets](http://dbxtra.com/documentation/#topic/report-web-service/web-report-widget/web_report_widget.htm).

P.S.: I'm a DBxtra evangelist.